# Relative pronoun "that" for plural antecedent?

Tags: relative-pronouns

Can the relative pronoun "that" be used for a plural antecedent?

For example, I would like to know whether the following sentences are gramartically correct or not.

- I have two cars that are made in Japan.
- She got two candies that are very sweet.

I think "that" is usually singular pronoun like "That car is blue". "That cars are blue" is incorrect. So I am confused.

Comment: The relative _that_ is a different pronoun from the demonstrative _that_, and has different grammar. It is not marked for gender or number, and may be used for people or things. It may be deleted if it is not the subject of the relative.

Comment: @JohnLawler I did not know "The relative that is a different pronoun from the demonstrative". Thank you very much!